# slideToggle and responsive width changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

This question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817340/jquery-slidetoggle-displaynone) a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384461/trouble-with-a-responsive-menu-and-jquerys-slidetoggle) times before years ago. I am basically asking if there is a more up to date 'cleaner' way of handling this problem.

I am using `slideToggle` on a button to show and hide a menu div when the screen is small. However, the style is added inline.

Without clicking the button

```
<div class="nav">...</div>
```

Toggling the button once

```
<div class="nav" style="display: block;">...</div>
```

Toggling the button twice

```
<div class="nav" style="display: none;">...</div>
```

So this leads to a situation where after toggling the button twice the in-line style of `display: none` remains on the div. So if I then change the width of the screen so that the button disappears the menu is still hidden when it should be visible.

Is there a clean way of dealing with this issue?

Comment: You could stop using `slideToggle` and use `toggleClass` with a predefined class instead. This way you can control what's happening exactly. I'll post an answer with a working example soon.

Comment: or you can add media queries to add separate styling for both situations (small and no-small screen)

Comment: what is the problem with [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384461/trouble-with-a-responsive-menu-and-jquerys-slidetoggle)...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery solution that doesn't require `refresh()` on a predefined screen width

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navbar-toggle').click(function() {
        // Toggle navbar button animation
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        // Toggle navbar menu
        $('.site-nav-container').slideToggle(500, function() {
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
                // Remove inline class
                $(this).css('display', '');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, you could stop using `slideToggle` and use `toggleClass` instead.

Here, I emulate the `slideToggle` effect with a combination of `max-height` and `transition` :

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $('.test').toggleClass('shown');
});
```

```css
.test{
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
}

.shown{
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>

<button>Toggle !</button>
```

Comment: Your example doesn't take screen size into account.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap library for toggling options and many more functionalities. 
You can see example here, [Bootstrap collapse.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#example)

Answer (score 0):

Run into this situation today and I fixed it using `$(window).resize` event. My case was similar to yours: I had a jQuery function that `slideToggle()` my `ul` containing the menu but, when my nav was toggled off and I resized the window back to desktop-size, I couldn't see the nav bar anymore because I had in-line style `style="display: block;"`.

So, my solution was listening for window resize and check if the `ul` was hidden (my `ul` has a class called `nav` and my breakpoint is 667 px).

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(this).width() > 667 && $(".nav").is(":hidden")) {
        $(".nav").removeAttr("style");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace slideToggle code with below piece of code:

```
var sel = $('.nav');
if(sel[0].style.display === 'block') {
            sel[0].style.display = 'none';
            sel[0].style.display = '';
        } else {
            sel[0].style.display = 'block';
        }
```